# Ubuntu 12.10 - VirtualBox not sharing internet with guest system

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I went from ArchLinux to Ubuntu on my dev box. I use VirtualBox to test web sites on Windows and IE. I have my Windows 7 VirtualBox image running on Ubuntu's VirtualBox. Back with ArchLinux, internet worked "out of the box" on the Windows boxes. I left the default options on the box's Network Options (NAT).

The Windows machine shows as "connected to ethernet" but reports:

> The dns server isn't responding

So I can't access Internet from there. I tried searching for Ubuntu's official docs but they seem pretty outdated. I tried using my old boxes from Arch (which boot normally but have no internet) and creating a new box from Ubuntu itself, but still get the same results.

Update:
I'm using VirtualBox 4.1.18 from Ubuntu's repository (apt-get install virtualbox).

Comment: Does your Windows client get all network configuration by DHCP? Make sure you've set that correctly in the interface configuration. Secondly, what version of VirtualBox did you install? regular from virtualbox.org or -ose from Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: Apparently yes, the Windows machine is configured to get all network configurations from DHCP.

Comment: Can you reach the address as being the DNS server? (e.g. `ping 192.168.123.1`)

Comment: How do I know what the IP for the DNS should be?

Comment: You get it via DHCP... so, just check the details on the interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/10864), either:

- Upgrade Virtualbox at least to 4.2.2 (the better way to do it is adding the official repository, see [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) under Debian based distributions)
- Configure dns by hand inside the virtual machine (you can use 8.8.8.8, Google, open dns, or your ISPs server as your virtual machine dns server).

Comment: Thanks! I upgraded to 4.2.2 from the official repo and it's working fine now.

Comment: There is no 4.2.2, I can only see 4.2.12 https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: Please note that I said *at least*, 4.2.12 will be fine ;).